# How to modify a tag text value based on its sibling tag text value in xml with python?

Tags: python, xml, jenkins

For Eg:

```
<parameterDefinitions>
        <hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition>
          <name>name</name>
          <description></description>
          <defaultValue>abc</defaultValue>
        </hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition>
        <hudson.model.BooleanParameterDefinition>
          <name>branch</name>
          <description></description>
          <defaultValue>true</defaultValue>
        </hudson.model.BooleanParameterDefinition>
</parameterDefinitions>
```

Above given is the small part of XML file which am getting from the Jenkins server. I need to modify the default value(abc and true for the above eg) of the parameters based on its respective name(name and branch).

Have read about MiniDom, Element and ElementTree but couldn't figure out the exact api. Can anyone help me out with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll cover ElementTree and Minidom.  I am unfamiliar with *Element*.

For these examples, we let

```
raw = """
    <parameterDefinitions>
        <hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition>
            <name>name</name>
            <description></description>
            <defaultValue>abc</defaultValue>
        </hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition>
        <hudson.model.BooleanParameterDefinition>
            <name>branch</name>
            <description></description>
            <defaultValue>true</defaultValue>
        </hudson.model.BooleanParameterDefinition>
    </parameterDefinitions>
""""
```

I'll demonstrate the api by changing the first *abc* default value to the value of the name element.  You can modify these to suit the change however you need to make it.

For ElementTree, we do

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.fromstring(raw)
node = root.find(".//hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition")
node.find(".//defaultValue").text = node.find(".//name").text
```

MiniDom is the most difficult to use here, as it doesn't have the advantage of understanding xpath.  However, to do the same, with the value of *raw* as above,

```
import xml.dom.minidom as MD
root = MD.parseString(raw)
node = root.childNodes[0].getElementsByTagName("hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition")[0]
defaultValue = node.getElementsByTagName("defaultValue")[0]
defaultValue.childNodes[0].replaceWholeText(node.getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue)
```

To loop over all the xParameterDefinition elements, in ElementTree, use

```
for x in ET.findall("./*"):
    # first time will be hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition
    # second time will be hudson.model.BooleanParameterDefinition
    # put loop body here
```

in Minidom, use

```
for x in root.childNodes[0].childNodes:
    if isinstance(x,MD.Element): # do this to avoid text nodes (ie newlines)
        # put loop body here
```

Finally, to turn the documents back into a string do

```
ET.tostring(root) # ElementTree
root.toxml() # minidom
```

Comment: I need to change the default value based on the name tag value(but not the name tag value itself) i.e i check in the .conf file for the value corresponding to the name tag and then copy it here. 
And i need to loop it for each parameter specified inside the parameter Definitions tag.

Comment: with the API u have provided am able to figure it out, but
`node.find(".//defaultValue").text = node.find(".//name").text'
will it reflect the modified content in the raw variable

Comment: No, raw is just a string.  To get the new xml as a string, in ET, use `ET.tostring(root)` and with minidom use `root.toxml()`.  And change the assignments to whatever you need the values to be; I only copied the values as an example, as you said you needed them to depend on the name, but didn't tell us how they need to depend on the name.

Comment: i've just provided only two parameters(hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition and  hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition) as an example, but there would be many as such. 
find() may find only one parameter everytime. How can i make it to loop for all the parameters inside?

Comment: what is that ".//" which u were using inside the find()?

Comment: That is an xpath expression.  The period means "this node" and the "//" means everything under it no matter how deep.  Thus `.//hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition` means all elements with that name anywhere in the document.  A single slash means only immediate children (which would have worked in that case).  [xpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) is a language for locating parts of an xml file, and is a must-know language if you work with xml much.  Notice how much nicer the ET example looks next to the MD example - that is because we are letting the xpath engine do all the work.

Comment: find() is not working in this case, i've changed find() to findall() then its working as expected. it would be better for other viewers if you can update find with findall

Answer (score 0):

Simplest try may be using `lxml.etree`  and grabbing the node by `xpath` (i.e. `//hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition/defaultValue` here) to be changed as below and changing properly-

```
from lxml import etree as et

data = """<parameterDefinitions>
        <hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition>
          <name>name</name>
          <description></description>
          <defaultValue>abc</defaultValue>
        </hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition>
        <hudson.model.BooleanParameterDefinition>
          <name>branch</name>
          <description></description>
          <defaultValue>true</defaultValue>
        </hudson.model.BooleanParameterDefinition>
</parameterDefinitions>"""

tree = et.fromstring(data)
w = tree.xpath("//hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition/defaultValue")
w[0].text = "changed"# here w is a list
print et.tostring(tree,pretty_print=True)
```

Output-

```
<parameterDefinitions>
        <hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition>
          <name>name</name>
          <description/>
          <defaultValue>changed</defaultValue>
        </hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition>
        <hudson.model.BooleanParameterDefinition>
          <name>branch</name>
          <description/>
          <defaultValue>true</defaultValue>
        </hudson.model.BooleanParameterDefinition>
</parameterDefinitions>
```